# MYSQL - select one specific record plus random records

Tags: mysql

Thought I had this cracked but doesn't seem to be quite working. Trying to display one specific image url based on logged in username ($user), plus other random image urls (not equal to $user).

When page is refreshed image is there, but not always. I need to always display image based on $user without fail. Any ideas how I can always include record based on $user? All records have to be in random order. Would it work better with a UNION?

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT A. * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM images
WHERE approved ='Y' 
ORDER BY (username = '".$user."') DESC, RAND()      
LIMIT 10) 
as A ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Have tried the following UNION but still can't seem to do it:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM   images 
 WHERE  username = '".$user."' ) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
     FROM   images 
     WHERE  username != '".$user."' 
     ORDER  BY Rand() 
     LIMIT  9) `t` 
 ORDER  BY Rand())
```

UNION always seems to exclude $user

When I try:

```
$photo=mysql_query("(SELECT * 
FROM   images 
 WHERE  username <> '".$user."' and approved = 'y'  ORDER  BY Rand() LIMIT     
10) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
 FROM   images 
 WHERE  username = '".$user."' and approved = 'y'
  ORDER  BY Rand()
 LIMIT  1) `t` )");
```

I get $user but it's always the last image. And only 9 images returned. Needs to be random order each time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove last `ORDER  BY Rand()` ;).

Comment: From 1st query? This now always excludes $user record

Comment: Do it in your 2nd query ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *all* images from the user, then you can do:

```
select i.*
from images i
order by (i.username = $user) desc, rand()
limit 10;
```

If you want exactly *one* image from the user, then your `union all` query should work.  If you want the desired user first, then use a subquery and the same `order by` clause:

```
select i.*
from ((select i.*
       from images i
       where i.username = $user
       order by rand()
       limit 1
      )  union all
      (select i.*
       from images i
       where i.username <> $user
       order by rand()
       limit 9
      )
     ) i
order by (i.username = $user) desc, rand();
```

If you have a lot of images (say thousands or more), then `order by rand()` is going to get expensive and you should investigate other methods for fetching what you want.

Comment: Have tried second query and now not getting $user at all. Only 9 rows returned.

Comment: @user1022772 . . . Perhaps the user isn't in the data.  I don't see how the second query could not include the user, given the first subquery.